# How to forward all SPA page requests through a Web Api controller?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an `angular application` and i want all requests that come through it first to pass through a `API Controller` in order to check roles or authorize.I do not want to alter all my `urls` so that they match the `Controller`:

I want all requests on that server to go through the controller first:

**Route examples**

```
localhost:4200/index
localhost:4200/details
localhost:4200/data/3
```

Currently my pipeline in the `Startup` looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa => {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "WorkingApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

**Controller**

```
using Serilog;
public class AuthController : ControllerBase {

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AuthenticationResult>> GetUsernameAndRolesAsync() {
            try {
                var result = new AuthenticationResult() {
                    Username = User.Identity.Name,
                    Roles = User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                                       .Select(x => x.Value)
                                       .ToList()
                };
                Log.Information($"GetUsernameAndRolesAsync returned IsAuthenticated={User.Identity.IsAuthenticated} for username {result.Username}");
                foreach (var role in result.Roles) {
                    Log.Information($"GetUsernameAndRolesAsync returned role: {role} for username: {result.Username}");
                }
                return result;

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                return new StatusCodeResult(500);
            }
        }

    }



public class AuthenticationResult {

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public List<string> Roles { get; set; }

    }
```

How do i alter my `MVC` template and the pipeline in order for all requests to pass seamlessly through my controller?

Comment: Having tried this in the past, I'd not recommend it, really not worth the hassle. As @TonyNgo says, you're best off authenticating your API endpoints and handling auth failures client side, as well as maybe passing back an object containing a list of permissions, which you can then use with auth guards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this requirement

> i want all requests that come through it first to pass through a API
>   Controller in order to check roles or authorize

That is not recommend approach because if you want to check permission of the user to access the resource angular already provide a `guard`. Guard use to check user permission and authorization.

.Net Core web api have `Authorize` attribute to check user permission to access the API resource normally usng SPA you need to implement JWT. The token will store in the client side and when user request API resource we send the request with the token in the header to let server know who is requesting the resource